# storing devexpress appointments in container and dragging and dropping them

Tags: c#, devexpress, scheduler

I have a devexpress scheduler in a WorkWeekView and a class with data objects which hold start and end datetime aswell as a location. How can i store those objects as appointments in a seperate container and be able to drag and drop those appointments into the scheduler? I want to keep the style of the appointments, as they're displayed within the scheduler.

Thanks in advance